# Custom CSS webkit scrollbar is not working in Firefox brwoser

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, webkit

Here is my fiddle : [SCROLLBAR](https://jsfiddle.net/inchrvndr/h41zueeu/3/)

Run the fiddle in both Chrome and Firefox browsers, hit the "Toggle" button  to see custom CSS not being applied for scroll bar in Firefox browser.

Is there a way I can display the custom scroll bar in all browsers?

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
}
/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: #c1bdbe;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
  background: #555D69;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox doesn't support custom scrollbars yet so there's no way to do this in css. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar

You have to use JavaScript to have global style on all browsers.